# Using Windows Live Writer with XWiki

Tags: blogging, windows-live-writer

Is it posible to use [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) with Windows Live Writer?

If it is possible can someone describe what needs to be configured? 
XWiki, Live Writer or both?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask this on the Xwiki's user mailing list. There is a great community behind it and you'll get competent & straightforward answers from the developers.